# Filter By Time Without Date in datetime64

Tags: pandas, datetime, time

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column called `my_date_time` and its type is `datetime64`.

How can I filter by just the time portion?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
df[some_magic_func(df['my_date_time']) < '09:30:00.123456']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to filter :

```
df.loc[df.my_date_time.dt.time<pd.to_datetime('09:30:00.123456').time()]
```

Comment: you can use `pd.to_datetime` as well, no need to also use the `datetime` module here

Comment: @MrFuppes okay.updated to use pd.to datetime.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, one extra related question -- what if I want to filter a DatetimeIndex with 2 disjointed time ranges (not datetime)?

Comment: you can pass df.index in the filter criteria..and you can pass range as well..but what do you mean by disjointed? can you give example values?